# How to close the Python turtle window after it does its code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm working on a simple program in Python 3.5 that contains turtle graphics
and I have a problem: after the turtle work is finished the user has to close the window manually.

Is there any way to program the window to close after the turtle work is done?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`turtle.bye()`, aka `turtle.Screen().bye()`, closes a turtle graphics window.

Usually, a lack of `turtle.mainloop()`, or one of its variants, will cause the window to close because the program will exit, closing everything. `turtle.mainloop()` should be the last statement executed in a turtle graphics program unless the script is run from within Python IDLE -n which disables `turtle.mainloop()` and variants.

`turtle.Screen().mainloop()` and `turtle.done()` are variants of `turtle.mainloop()`.

`turtle.exitonclick()` aka `turtle.Screen().exitonclick()` binds the screen click event to do a `turtle.bye()` and then invokes `turtle.mainloop()`

Comment: This does not help, next run ends with strange error:
`
\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py in _update_data(self)
   2645
   2646     def _update_data(self):
-> 2647         self.screen._incrementudc()
   2648         if self.screen._updatecounter != 0:
   2649             return

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py in _incrementudc(self)
   1291         if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
   1292             TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
-> 1293             raise Terminator


`

Comment: @bmi, if you want help with your issue, post a question to SO (not within a comment) including your (runnable) code and the error message.

Comment: cdlane, I finally found a solution, it's not a shame to let others know that this solution doesn't always work. Don't be afraid of it.

Answer (score -1):

Add `tkinter.mainloop()`at the end of the file.

example

```
import turtle
import tkinter as TK

t = turtle.Pen()
for x in range(100):
    t.forward(x)
    t.left(90)

TK.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code doesn't work as shown and the proposed solution is the opposite of what the OP is after -- `mainloop()` keeps the window open, it doesn't close it.  Leaving the `mainloop()` off of the end of the file will allow the window to close.

Comment: @clane at least you *can close the window* with this code. If you omit this code, then you can't even close the window manually. Thus, while not 100% on spot, it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try `exitonclick()` or `done()` at the end of the file to close the window .

Comment: Are there any other methods except those two? I'm running a code using IDLE, and it does not work out as I expected.

Comment: `turtle.done()` does not close the window, it's a synonym for `turtle.mainloop()`, which transfers control to the tkinter event loop which keeps the window open until some user action closes it!