# Stop mainloop in turtle by check variable

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to write program with turtle python that ask the user for a number and let him click on the screen the same number of times.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
count = 0

def up_count(x,y):
  global count
  count = count + 1
  print count
  return

def start():

  num1=int(raw_input("enter number"))
  print "in the gaeme you need to enter number and click on button",num1,"times"
  s = t.getscreen()
  if not num1 == count:
    s.onclick(up_count)
  else:
    t.mainloop()


start()
```

The problem is that I can not get out of mainloop when num1 == count.

How can I get out of mainloop?

I use https://repl.it/@eliadchoen/BrightShinyKernel for the program.

Comment: Minor: you don't need `global count` in the second function, because it doesn't change this global variable.

Comment: Acc to the docs [mainloop](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#turtle.mainloop) *starts* the eventloop rather than getting out of it. You can check out [How to close a python turtle window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826570/how-to-close-the-python-turtle-window-after-it-does-its-code)

Answer (score 0):

You don't *get out* of `mainloop()` until you're done with your use of turtle graphics. For example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

count = 0
number = -1

def up_count(x, y):
    global count
    count += 1

    if number == count:
        screen.bye()

def start():
    global number

    number = int(raw_input("Enter number: "))
    print "You need to click on window", number, "times"

    screen.onclick(up_count)

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

start()

mainloop()

print "Game over!"
```

My guess is this isn't your goal, so explain what it is you want to happen, in your question.