# Python turtle.done() alternatives - how do they differ?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I've seen python turtle programs use `turtle.done()`, `turtle.mainloop()` and `turtle.exitonclick()` apparently interchangeably. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) give an example where they just use `done()` (which would be `turtle.done()` with `import turtle`.

Is there a reason to ever use anything but `turtle.done()`, which is my preferred command?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that `turtle.done()` is an alias for `turtle.mainloop()` so the two are *identical*.  The `turtle.exitonclick()` does what `turtle.mainloop()` does, but adds an event handler (the program exits when you click anywhere on the window.)

For more detail, see these specific answers to these questions:

[How to close the Python turtle window after it does its code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42283059/5771269)

[Python: How to reset the turtle graphics window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260054/5771269)

There is some subtlety in choice when moving between Python 2 and Python 3 as some of these change from *functions* to *methods*.

Comment: OK, thank's. I'm still slightly confused though - is the only difference in terms of behaviour that `exitonclick()` closes when the used click anywhere on the screen, but with the other two they have to click the `X` in the top-right of the the window to exit?